# Strange visual glitch with button and dynamically changed height

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a button with a ::before pseudo element as a background, to achieve an animated hover effect, and above this button there's a carousel with adaptive height.

My problem is that when the user changes the slide to another with a different height, the button realocation shows some problems, and the worst is that I can't reproduce it on Codepen (I tried [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbwJyE) but the glitch is not happening), so I captured the glitch and posted on YouTube, you can see the video clicking [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zVv37CI-EE).

By the way, this is the relevant CSS I have in the button:

```
.btn-block{
    position: relative;
    transition: .15s ease-out;
    transition-property: color;
}
.btn-block::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: .15s ease-out;
    transition-property: background, padding, border-radius;
}
.btn-block:hover::before{
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

Is there something I can do about this glitch, or is there another way to achieve the hover effect I want?

Comment: Removed every transition, didn't solve the problem

Comment: give your slider a `min-height`. the slides have different height thats why the button is moving.

Comment: The problem is not the button moving, the problem is the visual glitch that can be seen in the video (the border and the background - a ::before pseudo element - moving separately). Yes, the slider has a dynamic height, and it animates the height according to the current slide content, but you can see it working in the codepen link that is in the question.